# How to pick and show particular values from json with dart (flutter)?

Tags: json, dart

I am an absolute beginner and would appreciate your help very much.
My json is as follows:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "hmip.0.homes.18c6789e-30e6-46c3-ba4b-1f94d284c178.weather.humidity",
    "val": 73,
    "ts": 1661671736783,
    "ack": true
  },
  {
    "id": "hmip.0.homes.18c6789e-30e6-46c3-ba4b-1f94d284c178.weather.temperature",
    "val": 16.8,
    "ts": 1661671736782,
    "ack": true
  },
  {
    "id": "hmip.0.homes.18c6789e-30e6-46c3-ba4b-1f94d284c178.weather.weatherCondition",
    "val": "CLEAR",
    "ts": 1661671736783,
    "ack": true
  },
  {
    "id": "hmip.0.homes.18c6789e-30e6-46c3-ba4b-1f94d284c178.weather.weatherDayTime",
    "val": "DAY",
    "ts": 1661671736783,
    "ack": true
  },
  {
    "id": "hmip.0.homes.18c6789e-30e6-46c3-ba4b-1f94d284c178.weather.windDirection",
    "val": 10,
    "ts": 1661671736784,
    "ack": true
  },
  {
    "id": "hmip.0.homes.18c6789e-30e6-46c3-ba4b-1f94d284c178.weather.windSpeed",
    "val": 18.503999999999998,
    "ts": 1661671736784,
    "ack": true
  }
]
```

When I want to pick and show a particular value, e.g. for humidity, I get the following error:

> type 'String' is not a subtype of 'int' of 'index'

My dart-code is as follows:

```dart
class EinzelwerteList {
  final List<Wetter> einzelwerte;

  EinzelwerteList({
    required this.einzelwerte,
  });

  factory EinzelwerteList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<Wetter> einzelwerte = <Wetter>[];
    einzelwerte = parsedJson.map((i) => Wetter.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return new EinzelwerteList(einzelwerte: einzelwerte);
  }
}

class Wetter {
  final String id;
  final Int val;
  final Int ts;
  final Bool ack;

  Wetter({
    required this.id,
    required this.val,
    required this.ts,
    required this.ack,
  });

  factory Wetter.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Wetter(
        id: json['id'].toString(),
        val: json['val'],
        ts: json['ts'],
        ack: json['ack']);
  }
}

Future<Wetter> fetchWetter() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'http://192.168.178.37:8087/getBulk/hmip.0.homes.18c6789e-30e6-46c3-ba4b-1f94d284c178.weather.humidity,hmip.0.homes.18c6789e-30e6-46c3-ba4b-1f94d284c178.weather.temperature,hmip.0.homes.18c6789e-30e6-46c3-ba4b-1f94d284c178.weather.weatherCondition,hmip.0.homes.18c6789e-30e6-46c3-ba4b-1f94d284c178.weather.weatherDayTime,hmip.0.homes.18c6789e-30e6-46c3-ba4b-1f94d284c178.weather.windDirection,hmip.0.homes.18c6789e-30e6-46c3-ba4b-1f94d284c178.weather.windSpeed'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
// If the server did return a 200 OK response,
// then parse the JSON.
    var dataDecoded = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var humidity = dataDecoded['einzelwerte'][0]['val'].toString();
    debugPrint(humidity);

    return Wetter.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
// If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
// then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load Wetter');
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Wetter> futureWetter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureWetter = fetchWetter();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        //scaffoldBackgroundColor:
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Micha lernt Flutter & Dart'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Wetter>(
            future: futureWetter,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.val.toString());
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              return Container();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What do I do wrong?

As I said I am a total newbie and try to learn. So please be patient even if I ask dumb question.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems but the specific problem you are getting right now is the following piece of code:

```dart
    var dataDecoded = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var humidity = dataDecoded['einzelwerte'][0]['val'].toString();
```

The JSON does not contain a `Map` as the first level but instead a `List`. So you are getting an error since a `List` expects an `int` inside the `[]` while you are providing a `String`.

Another problem, you are going to have later, is that you are using the wrong types in your `Wetter` class. The types `Int` and `Bool` comes from `dart:ffi` and is meant to be used if you are integrating with native C code.

You should instead use `int` and `bool`.

A third problem is that `val` in your JSON contains a mix of types. So in your example you can see it is sometimes `double` and other times `int` and sometime `String`... the mix of `int` and `double` can be solved by use the `num` type but you need to add some custom handling for the `String`.

Comment: Thank you. I will work that out and give feedback as soon as I can.